# Как создать функцию смены стиля элемента при нажатиях?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как создать функцию смены стиля элемента при нажатиях? Например, при первом клике черный фон, при втором - красный, и при последующих кликах повторение этой функции, т.е. как бы цикл смены цветов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let element = document.querySelector('.element');

let arr = ['#2ecc71', '#3498db', '#9b59b6'];
let curColor = 1;
element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (curColor == 3) {
        curColor = 0;
    }
    element.style.backgroundColor = arr[curColor++];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Кликните в любом месте:

```js
let a = 'black';
document.onclick = _ => {
    a = a == 'red' ? 'black' : 'red';
    document.bgColor = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я смог сделать более простой способ. Можно еще с помощью `switch`.

```js
const a = document.querySelector('body');

let b = "white";

function c(){
    if (b == "white") {
        document.body.style.cssText = "background: black;";
        b = "black"
    }
    else if(b == "black"){
        document.body.style.cssText = "background: white;";
        b = "white"
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="c()">YEEE</button>
```